# VB.net invalid length for a base 64 char array or string

Tags: vb.net, encoding, base64, formatexception

I have an issue with conversion from a base-64 string to normal, readable text. I did some research and found that base 64 strings have to be of a length that is a multiple of 4. So I used padRight to give it a valid length, but I keep getting the same error. For example, I enter "hi" and it encodes as "⚫aGk====", which seems like 8 characters to me (which is obviously a multiple of 4). When I try to read it, it reads in with a length of 1.
I'm also using a custom file extension that I just called ".bgs". I'm not sure if that does anything. Writing to this file as a base64 string and reading/decoding it is the only thing I'm trying to do.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Using bs As New BinaryWriter(File.Open("saveFile.bgs", FileMode.Create))

        Dim originText As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim cipherText As String

        Dim byteArray As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(originText)
        cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray)

        Dim realLength As Integer = cipherText.Length() + 1
        Dim len As Integer = (realLength Mod 4)
        If (len > 0) Then bs.Write(cipherText.PadRight(realLength + (3 - len), "="))


        bs.Close()

    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Using bs As New BinaryReader(File.Open("saveFile.bgs", FileMode.Open))

        Dim cipherText2 As String = bs.Read()
        Dim originText2 As String = "Failed"

        TextBox2.Text = cipherText2.Length() 'reports length of 1
        Try
            Dim byteArray2 As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText2)
            originText2 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray2)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        'TextBox2.Text = originText2

    End Using
End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Update: it looks like the first character (the dot in the case above) seen in the .bgs file when I open it with notepad controls the contents of cipherText2, which is just a number, explaining why the length is so low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base64 encodes using only printable ASCII characters.

You are seeing the dot because you are using binary writer which [prefixes strings with their length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzxa6408(v=vs.110).aspx) when writing to file.

Then you are using `Read` instead of `ReadString` so you read the string length as a number (which is then implicitly converted to string because you are not using `Option Strict On` like you should).

You can fix it by using `ReadString` instead of `Read`, but it would be easier if you used a text writer.

You also should not try to pad results of `ToBase64String`. It already gives you the correct string.

I would rewrite your code as:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim originText As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim cipherText As String = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(originText))

    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("saveFile.bgs", cipherText, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim cipherText2 As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("saveFile.bgs", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)
    Dim originText2 As String = "Failed"

    originText2 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText2))

    'TextBox2.Text = originText2
End Sub
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks very much!